# firebase rules write for auth user but delete only its own data

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

is there a way to let users only delete their own data? auth users can write to FB and read other users data but only can delete theis own data.

could it be that write rule includes the delete rule?

like:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read; 
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write permission does include delete.  This is stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

> A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a write rule can be broken into create, update, and delete

So, if you grate write access, you are implicitly granting create, update, and delete.  You might want to break them up separately:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read; 
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userid;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```